# about the Laguerre square expansion Sin(x)

Tags: calculus, laguerre-polynomials

The following functional series are developments using Laguerre polynomials, the second is the square of the Laguerre polynomial, the first is half as fast as the second being this is the square of the Laguerre polynomial, this being non-orthogonal
How is this possible??
$$\sin (x z)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} (-1)^n i^n z^n \left(z^2+1\right)^{-n-1} \left((z-i) (1+i z)^n+(-1)^n (z+i) (1-i z)^n\right) L_n(x)$$
$$\frac{\sin (x z)}{x z}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(L_n^{\alpha }(x) L_n^{\alpha }(-x)) \left((-1)^{2 n} z^{2 n} \Gamma (n+1)^2 \, _3F_2\left(n+\frac{\alpha }{2}+\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{\alpha }{2}+1,n+\alpha +1;n+\frac{3}{2},2 n+\alpha +2;-z^2\right)\right)}{\Gamma (2 n+2)}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "half as fast"?. What speed are you referring to?

Comment: the speed is referred to the same number of terms in the series to the value of the error obtained, for example for n = 10 the first one reaches an error of $$-\text{2.1271952979677565$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-10}$$ while the second gives$$\text{3.7336775849919585$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-25}$$